# Tooltips flicker on OSX

Tags: macos, javafx, javafx-2

I'm creating a cross-platform GUI using JavaFX 2.0, and some of the controls that I use require tooltips to be displayed when the mouse hovers over them. I've got the tooltips displaying fine on my Windows 7 machine, but on OSX (10.7.3) the tooltips appear and then dissapear immediately, and the only way to get them to display again is to move the mouse off the control and then back on.

Is this a known issue with tooltips under OSX, or is there something special that needs to be done?

Many thanks,

Joseph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a known issue [RT-14798 "Mac: tooltips disappear right after they are displayed"](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-14798), which was fixed on January 26, 2012.  Download the latest [JavaFX OS-X early access release](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html) and, if you are still having an issue, reopen the bug.  Signup is required to access the bug tracker, but anybody can signup and create or comment on bugs and issues.